# how to find the author who uploaded cookbook to chef server?

Tags: chef-infra, metadata, devops, chef-recipe, cookbook

how to find the author who uploaded the cookbook to the chef server?
Also how to find out the versions mapping to the author of the cookbook upload in chef-server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to find the author who uploaded the cookbook to the chef server?

It should not be possible to get users who uploaded cookbooks from Chef Server dashboard or even with API.
However you can analyze logs. Specifically every action performed over Chef Server is logged in `/var/log/chef/server.log`. 
If you identify the log pattern for cookbook upload you can also setup a notification system using ELK stack.

> Also how to find out the versions mapping to the author of the cookbook upload in chef-server?

Also here. It can be done analyzing results of specific search performed on logs.

Comment: Strange. We used to receive number of versions uploads to the same cookbook many times in a day. SUrfing through logs would be difficult work.
I was expecting something like a column name named author near the cookbook version in the Chef Server UI.

Comment: Yes. That kind of column would be very useful. Unfortunately currently only way seems to be to check on logs as on my answer